# vim indentation correction not working correctly

Tags: linux, vim

I'm using vim to edit files that use a programming language where the end of line is not marked with ;. This causes problems when I try to fix indentation in vim. If I put a ; at the end then vim is able to correctly fix the indentation, but since this programming language doesn't have a ; at the end of a statement the indentation isn't correct after vim tries to fix it.

Here is the code correctly formatted:

```
if imageFound("foo.bmp")
{
    clickButton("button1.bmp")
    clickButton("button2.bmp")
}
```

If I do =G then in will turn into this, which is incorrectly formatted:

```
if imageFound("foo.bmp")
{
    clickButton("button1.bmp")
        clickButton("button2.bmp")
}
```

However, if I put a ; at the end of one of the lines the line underneath it will be correctly formatted.

```
if imageFound("foo.bmp")
{
    clickButton("button1.bmp");
    clickButton("button2.bmp")
}
```

How can I make vim correctly fix the formatting without having to put a ; at the end of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:set cindent cinoptions=+0`.